# Go template not rendering

Tags: go, go-templates

I need to pass data to a Handler`(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request)`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"

    "local-pkg/pages"
    "local-pkg/structs"
)

var tmpl *template.Template
var htmlTags map[string]structs.Tags

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler).Methods("GET") //works fine

    data := pages.GetHTMLTags()
    http.HandleFunc("/", testHandler(data)) //-> {{define "index"}}{{template "header" . }}Index{{template "footer"}}{{end}}

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        data := pages.GetHTMLTags()
        page2Handler(w, r, data) //-> {{define "index"}}{{template "header" . }}Index{{template "footer"}}{{end}}
    })
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Printf("%T", tmpl)) //-> *template.Template
    data := pages.GetHTMLTags()
    err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", data["index"])
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

func testHandler(page map[string]structs.Tags) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Printf("%T", tmpl)) //-> prints nothing
        err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", page["index"])
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    }
}

func page2Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, data map[string]structs.Tags) {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Printf("%T", tmpl)) //-> prints nothing
    err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", data["index"])
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure the templates have been parsed & loaded in both use cases?

Comment: It should given the first approach, func indexHandler, is working fine.

Comment: They're all for the same route ... is this just for the example or possibly the issue?

Comment: The route "/" is just an example, when running the code I have to comment out all but one or the compiler complains.